# Can the first harmonic not be resonated?

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance

I'm confused by the following excercise:

> A violin string is put next to a speaker. The speaker goes through all the 
>   frequencies between 50Hz and 1500Hz. It is observed that the string only resonates at 880Hz and 1320Hz. [...]

These are the 2nd and 3rd harmonics respectively. However I would expect the first harmonic (the fundamental), which is also present in the [50, 1500]Hz interval to resonate. Why is this not the case?

**This question is not about how to solve it. In fact, I have not even given a the task, because it is irrelevant to my question.**

Comment: Probably there is a typo in the question. It makes sense if the range is from 500Hz to 1500Hz.

Comment: Whoever closevoted it, I don't really understand why. This is not how to solve the homework question, but about an underlying concept of physics so explicitely ontopic.

Comment: @verdelite so the answer to the question is, the fundamental can (and will be) resonated?

Comment: with the condition in your question I think the answer is "yes".

Comment: Knowing the rest of the question might help.  For example were you asked to find the fundamental based on this info?  Where you asked to explain why the fundamental was not present?  It could just be a poorly thought up question designed to test your ability to find f1 given part of a sequence.  My first thought was that perhaps these 2 notes are fundamentals of different strings.

Comment: You were supposed to calculate the tension of the string (length was given).